# QEMU/KVM - Getting "Error connecting to graphical console: Error opening Spice console SpiceClientGtk missing" when trying to create a VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, linux-kvm, spice

I am trying to create a virtual machine using QEMU/KVM.  I am getting an error:

Error connecting to graphical console: Error opening Spice console SpiceClientGtk missing

I have looked around but cannot find an answer that resolves this for me.
Note, this is not the same issue as in:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/833964/virt-manager-cant-connect-to-graphical-console

About my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux punko 4.15.0-124-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:54:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I had gir1.2-spiceclientgtk-3.0 and other needed modules installed. But it didn't help.

So I went to Hardware Details section, and changed Display settings from Spice Server to VNC server, and it worked. It could work also other way around if you have VNC server marked, then you could change to Spice Server.

Another thing that I found on forums and can help is changing Video from VGA to QXL model.